# Does calling supportInvalidateOptionsMenu in onCreateView work? (for actionbarsherlock)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Is it permitted to call SherlockFragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu from SherlockFragment.onCreateView? I couldn't find anything saying otherwise, but it seems like doing so may cause clicks on the menu items to not be handled until one exits the activity. (This happens on an API 8 emulator).

I have a fairly simple repro of this behavior. For some reason, it only happens when the activity did not add any menu items, but the fragment did.

Following is the code of the repro, if anyone is interested. What will happen is, the background will not turn red. However, if you comment out getSherlockActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(), it does turn red.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.frag_container);

    FunFragment frag = new FunFragment();

    FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    trans.add(R.id.frag_container, frag, "foobar");
    trans.commit();
}
```

}

```
public class FunFragment extends SherlockFragment {
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getSherlockActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    return new View(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.add(0, 5, 0, "Do magic").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 5:
        getView().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFFFF0000));
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can just call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` instead of `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: They do the same thing (supportInvalidateOptionsMenu just calls invalidateOptionsMenu)